# post back when session expires in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, session

On one of my pages I have a div that uses ajax to load content asyncrohnously. When a session expires the user is supposed to be redirected back to the loggin screen. However, when the session expires and the ajax call is triggered the login page gets put inside the div. What I want is for the user to be redirected back to the login screen.

Answer (score 2):

One way of solving this is to add a text to uniquely identify the login page and use it in AJAX call back to redirect to a login page again. Here is a sample code using `jQuery global callbacks`....

```
$(document).bind("ajaxComplete", function(event, response, ajaxOptions) {
    if (response.status == 200 && response.responseText.match(/LOGIN_PAGE_UNIQUE_KEY/)) {
        self.location = "/web/login?timeout=1";
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Glad I can help. If you like the answer and it solved your problem, accept it by clicking on the tick mark. This will help other people to know which may be best solution for their problem

Comment: Interestingly enough, this worked for us without adding any kind of unique key. Reason being is the ajax calls we were doing were partial views in MVC, so if they succeeded the responseText was just the html of the partial. But if it failed the login screen would load in the div and the responseText would automatically include whatever "LOGIN_PAGE_UNIQUE_KEY" you inserted, because the script itself was being returned in the responseText. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I think that extension headers is the key, the login page could send additional header to be captured by the xmlhttprequest handler.

Or in a more lazy and unreliable approach, use a javascript on the login page, if the location of the current page is not the login one,  then use javascript to redirect (it depend on javascript but as you are making xhr request).

Comment: This seems to be a nice lazy trick. Has anybody tested this ? Feeling lazy to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Send a notification back to the JavaScript that the session is no longer valid. When the JavaScript gets the appropriate error, have it `window.location = http://example.com/`.